# VirutalBox headless VM + 3D acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, 3d, headless

I have installed virtualbox on my Ubuntu 13.10 (desktop) host, configured windows 7 guest, added extension pack and guest additions. My intention is to work on windows 7 remotely, so I have configured rdp on win7 and init.d on the host to start VM at boot in headless mode.

However, I've noticed that VM could not start with 3D acceleration in headless mode IF virtualbox GUI is not started (error). What is interesting, that it starts from ssh console in headless mode with 3D acceleration if virtualbox (with gui) already started on host.

What I want to know is if there is an option to start VM in headless mode with 3D acceleration WITHOUT virtualbox GUI started?

Here is my error:

```
Error: failed to start machine. Error message: This VM was configured to use 3D acceleration. However, the 3D support of the host is not working properly and the VM cannot be started. To fix this problem, either fix the host 3D support (update the host graphics driver?) or disable 3D acceleration in the VM settings (VERR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alas, no. The 3D acceleration option pipes calls through to 3D APIs of the host OS. When you start in headless mode, you're not using the graphics card, so no 3D support.

You won't get working 3D acceleration across RDP anyway, so you may as well disable it.

Comment: I'd like to use it not only via rdp, but on host machine too :( Assuming what you said, I do not understand, why it works in headless without any error messages when virtualbox window started (separately, from another console)?